# Rabin Karp algorithm that uses bitwise AND

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, number-theory

I'm reading the source code of JPlag and came across their rabin-karp algorithm implemented found [here](https://github.com/jplag/jplag/blob/250c1be5197463a3e26a919abc75b1b59b286093/jplag/src/main/java/jplag/GSTiling.java#L25).

Here's the gist of it:

```
// modulo = 63

            for (i=0; i<loops; i++) {
                hash -= factor * (s.tokens[i].type & modulo);
                hash = (2*hash) + (s.tokens[i+hashLength].type & modulo);
            }
```

What makes this a "good" hash function (or is it a terrible one)?

Couple of things I don't understand:

1. there isn't a modulus applied to the hash at each iteration of the loop unlike the [traditional rabin karp algorithm](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-f14/www/lectures/lec6/karp-rabin-09-15-14.pdf), so is there a "table size" this adheres to, and why?
2. `(2*hash)` - what is the significance of choosing 2 as the base? In the regular rabin-karp, the base is recommended to be larger than the character set size. 2 certainly isn't.
3. `(s.tokens[i+hashLength].type & modulo)` - What is the bitwise AND doing here?

Comment: 63 in binary is just 8 set bits in the LSBs and unset bits elsewhere. 

$x \land m = x \mod (m - 1)$ when $modulo$ is a power of 2.